# client side scripts producing non-valid HTML that validates

Tags: javascript, html, validation, client-side

I noticed using JavaScript I can produce HTML with mismatching tags that still pass the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check). For example

```
<script type="text/javascript>
document.write("<h4>This is large text<h2></h4> This is small text")
</script>
```

has unnested `</h4>` and no closing `<h2>` but the document still passes as HTML 5 (or whatever). Can this be an issue regarding browser compatibility and why is it not detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The w3 validator doesn't execute Javascript, nor should it. It only checks code that you have explicitly supplied to it.